# how to create a json format in our own format in android?

Tags: java, json

i like to create a JSON format to send to service. i format of the json in mentioned below.
the product object is came from loop. please assume i=1 and give me a answer.

```
{
    "tableid": 41,
    "status": 141,
    "products": [
        {
            "menuitemid": 349,
            "qty": "1",
            "taxids": [
                {
                    "taxid": "1",
                    "Amount": 0.15
                }
            ],
            "taxamount": 0.15,
            "seatname": "Seat 1",
            "modifiers": [],
            "saleid": "140704131457005701",
            "discountshiftlevelid": ""
        },
        {
            "menuitemid": 44,
            "qty": "1",
            "taxids": [
                {
                    "taxid": "1",
                    "Amount": 0.13425
                }
            ],
            "taxamount": 0.13425,
            "seatname": "Seat 1"
        },
        {
            "menuitemid": 44,
            "qty": "1",
            "taxids": [
                {
                    "taxid": "1",
                    "Amount": 0.13425
                }
            ],
            "taxamount": 0.13425,
            "seatname": "Seat 2"
        },
        {
            "menuitemid": 44,
            "qty": "1",
            "taxids": [
                {
                    "taxid": "1",
                    "Amount": 0.13425
                }
            ],
            "taxamount": 0.13425,
            "seatname": "Seat 2"
        }
    ],
    "checkdiscountshiftlevelid": "",
    "customerid": "0"
}
```

i tried many times i didn't get the result. my sample code is below.

```
package servicecall;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Savecheckandprint {

    public void calll() throws JSONException
    {
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        try {

            obj1.put("tableid", "41");
            obj1.put("status", "141");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject products = new JSONObject();
        try {
            products.put("menuitemid", "349");
            products.put("qty", "2");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        //jsonArray.put(obj1);
        jsonArray.put(products);



        JSONObject studentsObj = new JSONObject();
        studentsObj.put("", obj1);
        studentsObj.put("", jsonArray);



        String jsonStr = studentsObj.toString();

        System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr);
    }
}
```

am new to android. i don't know how to create a JSON structure like about. please help me. please help me.

Comment: its really hard to understand what you are asking, please take a little time to correct your grammer and ad more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i understand your question but you should look into using GSON which allows for easy JSON creation from Objects/classes

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

```
package servicecall;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Savecheckandprint {

    public void calll() throws JSONException
    {
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        try {

            obj1.put("tableid", "41");
            obj1.put("status", "141");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject products = new JSONObject();
        try {
            products.put("menuitemid", "349");
            products.put("qty", "2");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(products);

        try {

            obj1.put("products", jsonArray);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String jsonStr = obj1.toString();

        System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr);
    }
}
```